# Alternative to Android's Device ID?

Tags: android

I am using Google Cloud Messaging and to manage the users devices server side im storing the GCM Registration ID and the Users Device ID in my Database. You can get the Device ID like that:

```
public static String getDeviceID(Context context) {
    final String deviceId = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();

    if (deviceId != null) {
        return deviceId;
    } else {
        return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
    }
}
```

Since Android 6.0 i have a problem with that because to read the Devices ID you need to use the dangerous permission `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`. So when the user uses my App and the automatic background process to register for the GCM Service he get's automatically asked to grant permission for `make and manage phone calls` which, in my opinion, is totally confusing for the user. He would not understand why the app needs to `make and manage phone calls` and i also dont want another dialog box to explain the user why the app needs this permission. It would make the app complicated and somehow frustrating for some users.

I want to get around this so i have to ask if there is any alternative way to uniquly identify a users device without needing any dangerous permission.

It has to fullfill following requirements:

- It must be unique
- It must be always the same id for a single device also after uninstalling and reinstalling the app

The reason for that is simple:

- The user can have multiple devices
- There can be multiple users on one device

Ofcourse i could just set my target SDK to `< 23` but some day you have to update your system anyway when you need new features from the 6.0 or greater API.

I also dont want to give the user the freedom of decision for that purpose because if the user does not grant the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission it would mess up the whole live update, messaging and synchronization system of the App.

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to uniquely identify a device (btw device id will change after factory reset).  There are ways to identify a user, but not a device - that I know of anyway.  If you must have the permission, I think you're stuck with asking for it and explaining, if necessary, why the permission is needed.  Good luck, because I can't even get the permission dialog to appear when I try it.  :-(

Comment: Have you tried it with Support Packages? `if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, Globals.REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE); ....` where `this` was called inside a `Fragment` from the support packages. Until now i really hate the new permissions system. It makes so much more work and so much more obfuscated stuff for the user.

Comment: What's wrong with using **android.os.Build.SERIAL**?  You won''t even need to ask for any permissions.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I don't know if SERIAL is available on all devices. But it is deprecated in API 26. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL